# Mock Progress Bar using jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, progress-bar, sweetalert

i am writing unit test cases for a js file which contains Progress Bar library, how to mock this

> myjs.js

```
console.log("File that contains some js code....")
function myFunc(para1,para2){
  var par = para1 + para2;
  swal("Info",para);
  return 3;
}
var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(dynamic, {//some code here} );
```

i am planning to unit test this function named "myFunc" so , i have written a test script that contains below code:

> test.js

```
const $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
var ProgressBar = require('progressbar.js');
var myJs = require('myjs.js');
test('test if myFunc returns "3"',()=> {
 expect(myJs.myFunc).toBe(3);
 })
```

The myJs.js is loaded as a part of django template including the progressBar.js, while running this test case i get a error like ProgressBar is not defined.
[image: npm test test/test.js]

additionally there exists a sweetalert in myFunc, how to mock this as well , a part from ProgressBar ?
Any kind help is appreciable

Comment: Basic of unit testing is what ever packages you are importing you just need to mock it because it will be already tested, I think the ProgressBar is a 3rd party package so you need to mock it

Comment: `myjs.js` will be executed by `node` or `browser` ?

Comment: @AdityaBhave myjs.js will be executed in browser from a django template.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes, it is a third party package, but i have no idea on how to mock 3rdy party libraries

Comment: Like `jest.mock('progressbar.js');`.